# I am getting unexpected output in c ..can anyone explain why?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a;
printf("%..geeksforgeeks..%");

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Output : `%.0.geeksforgeeks..%`

can anyone explain why ???

Comment: `%` expects an argument, to print the percentage sign use `%%`.

Comment: try `printf("%%..geeksforgeeks..%%");`

Comment: Is %. some sort of printf flag perhaps?

Comment: %. is a precision identifier.  Probalby has something to do with that.

Comment: is this a homework question?

Comment: My best guess is that `%..g` is being treated as `%g` and the first floating-point argument register happens to contain zero, but then I don't know why there's a leading `%.` on the zero.  I'm not inclined to dig deeper; over-investigating undefined behavior can tell you fun things about the C implementation, but here I don't think it'll be all that useful.

Answer (score 4):

In a printf format string, `%` is used to signal the beginning of a conversion, such as `%d` for integer or `%f` for floating point.

If you're trying to print out an actual percent sign, use `%%` in the format string.

Alternatively, if you want to print that as a literal string, don't supply it as a the format string:

```
printf("%s", "%..geeksforgeeks..%");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you get this exact output, but the problem is that [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) uses `%` as a metacharacter, so if you want to print a *literal* percent sign, you have to double it.

```
printf("%%..geeksforgeeks..%%\n")
```

Alternatively, don't use `printf` to print literal strings:

```
fputs("%..geeksforgeeks..%\n", stdout);
```

Technically speaking, having more "live" (un-doubled) % signs in a `printf` string than the number of additional arguments (items to be formatted) triggers *undefined behavior*, which means the C library is allowed to do *anything it wants*, ranging from mildly surprising behavior like this up to and including crashing your entire computer.